# Infinite Subsets of Compact Sets

Tags: analysis

Claim (from Rudin 2.37): If E is an infinite subset of a compact set K, then E has a limit point in K.

Attempt: I follow the proof from the book, but have trouble understanding the first statement.

It seems clear that proof by contradiction is easy to do. I can start (as the book does) by assuming E has no limit point in K.

The book now claims that for each q belonging to K, there is a neighborhood V_q which contains at most 1 element of E.

I don't understand how this statement comes from q not being a limit point of E.

I know the definition of a limit point of a set is that for **every** neighborhood of the point, there is **at least** one element belonging to said set.

So shouldn't the book (after claiming there is no limit point in K) say that for every point in K, there is at least one neighborhood for each that does not contain an element of E?

Maybe someone can clarify? Thanks.

Comment: If $q\in E$, then any neighborhood of $q$ contains at least one element of $E$... that is, $q$ itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me write the definition of a limit point in symbols:

$$
\begin{aligned}
x\;\text{is a limit point of $E$}\iff&\forall r>0\;\;\exists y\in(E\setminus\{x\})\;\;d(x,y)<r.\\ \\ \text{This implies that}\\ \\ x\;\text{is not a limit point of $E$}\iff&\exists r>0\;\;\forall y\in(E\setminus\{x\})\;\;d(x,y)\geqslant r.
\end{aligned}
$$

That is, a point $x$ (not neccesarily an element of $E$) is **not** a limit point of $E$ if and only if there is a neighborhood $V$ centered at $x$ such that $V\cap E$ is either $\{x\}$ (if $x\in E$) or $\varnothing$ (if $x\notin E$).

Comment: Yes, thank you. This was useful, because then I was able to argue that if I cover my set K completely using these neighborhoods Vq, then by K's compactness I should be able to form a finite subcover which still covers K. But this finite subcover would have finite number of elements from E, since all Vq have only at most 1 element from E (what you call x). Clearly, this subcover won't cover the infinite set E. Since E is a subset of K, if finite collection of Vq can't cover E, it certainly can't cover the larger set K. Therefore, K can't be compact, which contradicts the original assumption.

Comment: Good, your proof is correct

Answer (score 0):

Suppose no $p\in K$ is a limit point of $E $. For each $p \in K$ let $V_p$ be a nbhd of $p$ such that $V_p \cap E=\{p\}$ if $p\in E$, and $V_p\cap E=\phi$ if $p \not \in E.$ Then $\{V_p : p \in K\}$ is an open cover of $K$ and $K$ is compact, so there exists a finite $C \subset K$ for which  $S=\{V_p : p \in C\}$ is a cover of $K$. Each member of $S$ contains at most one member of $E$, and every member of $E$ belongs to a member of $S$, and $S$ is finite, so $E$ is finite.